# Emulator does not want to show icons that are retrieved from API

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, ionic-framework

I created a weather app on ionic using Angular framework, when I run it through ionic by command of ionic serve the app shows the api images, but once I open the app in android studio the  emulator and the apk on my android phone does not show the api icons for the weather, but it show other api details but except the icons from the api, does anyone know the problem?

I tried to change devices on android but it does not work
I am expecting for the weather icons to show up

Comment: Check your console log. it should show an error. if so, what does it say?

Comment: console log for android studio or ionic